# Why does this code not compile in g++

Tags: c++, templates, g++

sample code given below is not compiled in g++. but it's working on visual studio.
is it possible to use Template member function inside template class in g++

```
class Impl
{
public:
        template<class I>
        void Foo(I* i)
        {

        }
};

template<class C>
class D
{
public:
        C c;
        void Bar()
        {
                int t = 0;
                c.Foo<int>(&t);
        }
};

int main()
{
        D<Impl> d;
        d.Bar();
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are the errors you are seeing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the statement in question depends on a template parameter, the compiler is not allowed to introspect `C` until instantiation. You must tell it that you mean a function template:

```
c.template Foo<int>(&t);
```

If you don't put `template` there, the statement is ambiguous. For understanding, imagine the following `C`:

```
class C { const int Foo = 5; }; 
...
c.Foo<int>(&t);
```

It looks to the compiler as if you compare a `const int` to an `int`, and comparing the result of that to some adress of `&t`: `(c.Foo<int) > &t`.

**The real solution** however is to omit the explicit template argument in the function call, and just do:

```
c.Foo(&t);
```

This is correct even in the case where such a `C` has a non-template member function `Foo(int)`. Generally, write template code with as few assumptions as possible (but not less).

Answer (score 4):

`Foo()` is a template-dependent name, so you need to put `template` in front of the invocation:

```
template<class C>
void D<C>::Bar()
{
    int t = 0;
    c.template Foo(&t);
}
```

Comment: You can also leave out `<int>`, resulting in `c.Foo(&t)`. That should work as well.

Comment: @evnu Yes to leaving out the `<int>` (as I did in my answer), no to leaving out the `template` (as you did in your comment).

Comment: @nsa BTW, if the answer is satisfactory to you, please accept it by checking the tick-mark.

Comment: @MichaelWild: Of course you can leave out the `template` then.

Comment: @MichaelWild: And don't press on questioners to accept exactly _your_ answer, especially if the question is just a few minutes old. That's egoistic.

Comment: @phresnel Indeed, I stand corrected. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Another point: The version where you omit `template` will be correct even if `c.Foo()` is not a template, which is why I'd prefer it.