# Why cannot I compile my code with g+ in my terminal

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I have a directory with files that I am trying to compile into a *.exe,* but when I try to compile with this command in my terminal: "g++ -I ./*.cpp",

I get a very strange error:

> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../libmingwex.a(vsnprintf.o):(.text+0x0):
>   multiple definition of `vsnprintf';
>   C:....\AppData\Local\Temp\cc2FISpv.o:Inventory.cpp:(.text$vsnprintf[_vsnprintf]+0x0):
>   first defined here collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10187082/why-does-this-code-not-compile-in-g) which is for c, but the user talks about using a printf() function, but I use std::cout.

I am using [This json library](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) in my *.cpp file to store and retrieve data.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with full source code, compiler command and compiler version details

Comment: Can it be that you have syntax error in your code that you did not post and compiler complains about it? What answer do you expect?

Comment: @ÖöTiib i had moved from my ubuntu 19 laptop with the same code, and on the laptop it compiled perfectly fine...wheras this windows machine does not like it...could it be mingw vs gnu linux?

Comment: Seems to be a known mingw problem. From their mailinglist: [\[Mingw-users\] multiple definition of `vsnprintf'](https://osdn.net/projects/mingw/lists/archive/users/2019-August/000336.html), [\[Mingw-users\] multiple definitions of 'vsnprintf'](https://osdn.net/projects/mingw/lists/archive/users/2019-August/000333.html)